# Excel Scatter plot x-axis automatically reverting to 0 when range gets a certain size

Tags: excel, scatter-plot

I am making an XY scatter plot and error lines to make a sort of timeline, the dates along the x axis. This works wonderful but when the range of the data gets a certain length, the minimum on my scatter plot resets to zero instead of the automatic a setting of a few days before the earliest date.  Why does the scatter plot do this and how can I correct it. Ideally, the form will just always set the minimum to the earliest date. I know I can change it manually, but I am preparing this for a lot of users and really need this to set itself automatically and stay there.

[image]

Data set

[image]

What happens when I enter the next date
[image]

New Data set
[image]

Comment: what are the ranges used for your `X-Axis`, `Y-Axis` and `Error Bar`?

Comment: I may be miss understanding you. The data range that pulls that information is labeled in the pictures. The ranges for the table sets automatically when the data is inputted but there seems to be some sort of threshold will the minimum range automatically resets to zero instead of the minimum date in the range of data that pulls for the X-Axis. This causes my table to squish to the left and the only way I have seen to correct this is to manually enter the minimum in the Format Axis, but I can't expect others to know to do this. The intent is for this form to be usable by novice excel users.